# tr:last-child not working

Tags: css

Probably some stupid reason for it not working, but i tend to mess up the css a bit. So maybe it will apply to others aswell. CSS:

```
.bet_history table {
    width: 1000px;
    display: block;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.bet_history td {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    background: #0361ba;
    color: #BDD6CE;
}
.bet_history tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.bet_history tr:last-child {
    background: red;
}
.bet_history td.bet_history2 {
    color: #F0F0F0;
    width: 650px;
}
.bet_history td.bet_history1 {
    background-color: #0354a1;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.bet_history td.bet_history1:hover {
    color: #3399FF;
}
```

And here is the HTML: Edited!

```
<div id="main">

admin1<br />


<table class="bet_history">

<tr><td style="width: 250px;">Bet ID: #6. 09-22-2014 16:08</td><td class="bet_history1">Match ID #6</td><td class="bet_history2"><span style="color: #00FFFF;">10000</span> minerals on Cure(2.00). Your bet returned <span style="color: #00FFFF;">0</span> minerals. Better luck next time!</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 250px;">Bet ID: #5. 09-22-2014 16:06</td><td class="bet_history1">Match ID #4</td><td class="bet_history2"><span style="color: #00FFFF;">2222</span> minerals on Snute(2.30). Your bet returned <span style="color: #00FFFF;">5110.6</span> minerals. Congratulations!</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 250px;">Bet ID: #4. 09-22-2014 15:58</td><td class="bet_history1">Match ID #4</td><td class="bet_history2"><span style="color: #00FFFF;">2222</span> minerals on Snute(2.30). Your bet returned <span style="color: #00FFFF;">5110.6</span> minerals. Congratulations!</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 250px;">Bet ID: #3. 09-22-2014 15:25</td><td class="bet_history1">Match ID #5</td><td class="bet_history2"><span style="color: #00FFFF;">600</span> minerals on Lars(4.00). Your bet returned <span style="color: #00FFFF;">2400</span> minerals. Congratulations!</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 250px;">Bet ID: #2. 09-22-2014 12:03</td><td class="bet_history1">Match ID #3</td><td class="bet_history2"><span style="color: #00FFFF;">64</span> minerals on naniwa(9.00). Your bet returned <span style="color: #00FFFF;">576</span> minerals. Congratulations!</td></tr><tr><td style="width: 250px;">Bet ID: #1. 09-20-2014 16:00</td><td class="bet_history1">Match ID #1</td><td class="bet_history2"><span style="color: #00FFFF;">20</span> minerals on Snute(2.20). Your bet returned <span style="color: #00FFFF;">44</span> minerals. Congratulations!</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Why is the last-child not applying to the last tr? It will if i set it to td. Im sure its some stupid thing i did in the css.. This is no finished product. Im just wondering why the last-child doesnt work.

Comment: Is that the whole of your html, or is there supposed to be an `</table>` at the end? Not closing your table could be the problem.

Comment: I am closing the table. The echo is in a while-loop, mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: perhaps you could post the generated html (including the close-table-tag) instead of php. For example, if there is another element behind the current given code: Another reason that last-child might fail is that the `<tr>` is not the last element in its parent.

Comment: Edited now. Thanks for helping. I tried applying the style to the table instead. Nothing changed.

Comment: If you inspect the last `tr`, you'll see that the style **is applied to it**, however, you have addition stiles on it's `td` so you can't see the change. If you remove the `background` styles from it's `td`, you'll notice the change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Vucko mentioned in the comments the `tr:last-child` style is applied, however the td's in that row override that style.

If you want all the td's in the last row to be red edit your class to:

```
.bet_history tr:last-child td {
    background: red;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/1ecvoh1r/)**